# jQuery - how to make sticky navigation 'stick' in two cases? by default, and with top panel div expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, positioning, fixed

I have a "sticky navigation" that "sticks" to the top (function changes its position to :fixed, top:0) when the user scrolls down past it. I also have a 'expandalbe' sign in area at the top of the page. First problem was when I expand the sign in area at the top of the page, the point at which the navbar 'sticks' changes. Now I got it to stick when the panel is open, however when it is closed, it sticks at the wrong point (seems to stick at the point of additional height of the #panel). see fiddle

How do I make it so the #sticky_navigation sticks at top:0 in both cases -- when the #panel is open and closed/default?

*(Dead YouTube link removed)*

Thanks

```
   **// FIRST VERSION sticky navigaiton ------------//**
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;             
    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 })
        } else {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }       
    };

    sticky_navigation();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
    });

});
```

**UPDATE:**
Now I've got the it to work ONLY when the #panel is open. If it is closed, the #sticky_navigation does not initiate.

```
//sticky top nav PANEL OPEN ONLY
$(document).ready(function(){
    // grab the initial top offset of the navigation
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

    // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
    var sticky_navigation2 = function(){

        var scroll_top1 = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top
            scroll_top1 = $(window).scrollTop() - $('#panel').height();
        // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
        // otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top1 > sticky_navigation_offset_top ) {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 })
        } else {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }  

    };

    // run our function on load
    sticky_navigation2();

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation2();
    });

});
```

Comment: I have since switched to a different jQuery plugin that uses waypoints but it would still be very interesting to see if anyone could solve this dilemma

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#open").click(function() {
        var stickTop = $("div#sticky_navigation").offset().top;
        $("div#panel").slideDown("swing");
        $('#sticky_navigation').css('top',$("div#panel").height());

    });

    $("#panel").click(function() {
        $("div#panel").slideUp("swing");
        $('#sticky_navigation').css('top',stickTop);
    });


    $("#toggle a").click(function() {
        //$("#toggle a").toggle();
    });

});​
```

For a more accurate answer, create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

**Update**

You need to substract the `#panel`-height from your `$(window).scrollTop`-var `scroll_top1`.

For example:

```
var scroll_top1 = $(window).scrollTop() - $('#panel').height();
```

But, you need also to check if the #panel is visible or is not ;-)

**Update2**

Got it, just [take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/45kt7/show)!

```
//sticky top nav
$(document).ready(function(){
        // grab the initial top offset of the navigation
        var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

        // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
        var sticky_navigation = function(){

            var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop(),
                scrollHeightP = $(window).scrollTop() - $('#panel').height();
            var scroll_top1 = $('#panel:hidden') ? scrollHeight  : scrollHeightP; // our current vertical position from the top

            // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
            // otherwise change it back to relative
            if (scroll_top1 > sticky_navigation_offset_top ) {
                $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 })
            } else {
                $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
            }  

        };

        // run our function on load
        sticky_navigation();

        // and run it again every time you scroll
        $(window).scroll(function() {
             sticky_navigation();
        });

});
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to do the trick.. thank you very very much though for trying.

Comment: Hmm okay, I've misunderstood your problem! Make the site online and share your link here... So I can play a bit around!

Comment: Also- why does the sign in #panel close if clicked in? thats not good either

Comment: The login panel closes because you tell it to him! Under `// Collapse Panel` you do the following: `$("#panel").click(function(){ $("div#panel").slideUp("swing");});`

Comment: its still not working man. does it work for you? see my update

Comment: Okay, I've to accept! But, to time I can't figure out the problem. Sorry! I'll take a look tomorrow again, okay?!

Comment: nice logic, i like to implement it.